# Erlang typing discipline

Tags: erlang, strong-typing

Does Erlang feature strong typing or weak typing?
According to [this definition of strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing), looks like that Erlang features strong and weak typing at the same time.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Note that there is no single, formal definition of what it means to be "strongly typed"..

Comment: The wikipedia article is pretty bad, in particular the example they show. You can have automatic type conversions and still have a strongly typed language. Weak typing is more about the sort of thing you can do in C, such as converting an integer to a pointer, treating a struct a pointer as a struct b pointer, etc.

Comment: @RichardC Is there a documentation about the Erlang type system?

Comment: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang has strong dynamic typing as Python does.